# How to run ps-watcher as non-root

Tags: supervisord, monit

The command is

```
ps-watcher $HOME/ps-watcher.cfg
```

Is I run it as normal user, I got this error:

```
Unable to open file handle FH for file '/var/run/ps-watcher.pid': Permission denied
```

The content of ps-watcher.cfg is:

```
[tint2]
occurs = none
action = /usr/bin/tint2
```

Ironically, the man page says ps-watcher doesn't need to be run as root.

```
There's nothing in the ps command or ps-watcher, that requires one to run this daemon as root.
```

How to avoid the error? Can I change the path of /var/run/ps-watcher.pid?

Comment: What are the permissions of /var/run/ps-watcher.pid?

Comment: /var/run is owned by root. Turns out ps-watcher is a perl script. I have just changed the file path.

Comment: One solution is to modified ps-wather directly.
Change this line

    $PIDFILE = $ENV{'ps_watcher_pid_file'}; 

Then define an variable before calling ps-watcher.

    export ps_watcher_pid_file="$HOME/ps_watcher.pid"